# yum remove only single rpm file instead of all packages related to it

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

My environment: CentOS 7.0

1. Keep a rpm list by: `rpm -qa > before.list`
2. Try libreoffice-calc. (112M bytes) `yum install -y libreoffice-calc`
3. Think it is useless, I want to remove it. I found `yum remove libreoffice-calc` can only remove 25M bytes.

Is there smart method to remove other packages which was installed by dependency? (By the before.list?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps someday yum will be as smart as the latest Debian package utility which, I am told, records all of the dependencies when a package is installed so that when you remove the package, all of the dependencies that were installed for that package are also removed. Until such a version of yum becomes available, we have to do this chore ourselves and here are a couple ideas.

One idea is to run `rpm -qa > after.list` and then `diff -BurN before.list after.list`. However, if there has been many package updates since then, it might be difficult to determine the packages that you are looking to remove.

Another idea is to use the `--last` option of the rpm command to list the packages by date and time packages were installed:

```
rpm -qa --last > datetime_ordered.list
```

The packages that were installed on the same date and time as libreoffice-calc are most likely the dependencies that were needed by libreoffice-calc and the packages that you will want to remove using `yum remove` because yum will tell you whether there are more packages than libreoffice-calc that require those packages.

Comment: As I describe, this method only remove one rpm. During the process it will install many rpms. I typo for rpm install. And correct it to yum.

Comment: I have revised my answer to address your revised question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this most of the times with `yum history`.

From `man yum`:

```
history
   The  history  command allows the user to view what has happened in past transactions (assuming the history_record config. option is set).
    You can use info/list/packages-list/packages-info/summary to view what happened, undo/redo/rollback to act on that information and new to start a new history file.
```

It sometimes gets stuck on updates for which it cannot find the old package to restore the situation.

For simple installs I have found it pretty handy.

Answer (score 0):

while  its only available via plugin install:  yum-plugin-no-leaves

adding

--nodeps

or

--no-leaves
would also work

Comment: Your answer is sparse and a bit ambiguous.  Can you expand it a little to be more explicit?  Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234  not vague at all he needs to merely  add one or both of those triggers and to be totally  honest  YOU  seem to be a vampire type so please stop wasting comments on uselessness...if its so "vague" add to it   not some  retarded comment.